# php function namespace

Tags: php

in C , i can define a function to be static so it can only be used in it's own file.
in python , i can define a function with it's name starts with _  so this function can't be used outside this finle.

could i do it in php ?

Comment: functions != methods. Do you really mean "functions"? What is a "finle"?

Answer (score 2):

If you really mean "functions": No, both arent possible.

First: Functions are always static.

Second: In PHP namespaces are not bound to a file. So a file can declare non, one or more namespaces. On the other side a namespace can be declared in different files. Its difficult to define a consistent way on how non-public functions can get resolved. You can use static classes instead.

Comment: you say "both aren't possible" ,did you mean in c and python ? how ?    and you say : Functions are always static , in c? in python , or just in php ? i'm confused by what you say .

Comment: @mike: I dont know c and python well enough, but the question is about php, isnt? -- In PHP functions (!= methods) dont have a state (like methods in objects (properties)), so they can be treated as "always static". They are callable from everywhere (non-static methods require a object-context) and are not effected by anything else than the given arguments (thats not true at all, e.g. if it uses a time function or relies on the global state (ugly ;)).

Answer (score 0):

A class can be used to for data hiding and implementing encapsulation.

You can use `private` keyword to declare functions in php to hide them outside of code but the all are bounded with class.

Only class can use these type of functions.

```
class A
{
   /* This method will only be accessible in this 
      class only by the other methods of this class 
     and will be hide from rest of program code*/

  private function setValues()
  {
      //some stuff
  }
  public function getVal()
  {
     $this->setValues();
  }

}
```

The method above can only be accessible by this class.

Comment: Not quite the same as file scope though.

Comment: @deceze: I know but there is no other way to do this except class. I don't think there is something wrong if I explained using class instead